# How to display push notification if there are changes in DB using API?

Tags: java, android, react-native, push-notification, microservices

I have an android application which should display push-notification when there is a change in the table.
Say in the app if a student has change of rank from 2nd to 1st the teacher should get a notification and the list will be refreshed accordingly in app.
I'm using node-js to develop the API and firebase for push notification.
How can I reflect the change in database into the API and trigger push-notification to display it on the app and also it should monitor all the time to see if there is any rank changes in the database.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be all **backend dependent logic**, since changes in **DB**, whatever you are using depends on the technology used. For example if you are using Firebase Realtime DB then you can see the changes directly in application using SDK for anything else you have to work on api level and if any changes made successfully then you can trigger FCM or GCM  notifications. 
Here is few services you can use to achieve desired functionality.

[OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/)

[FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Comment: Hi Vikas,I have a clear picture of what you have commented.All that I need is how do you develop the backend logic for it connecting the FCM and DB

Comment: then please add some more code or details on, which DB are u using and which server side language are u using to develop api and other things which can help people to understand problem fully and help u, edit your tags also so that right people can answer your question.